# php Object constructor doesn't works

Tags: php, default-constructor

I want to instance an object into other object constructor.

My problem is that the first object `MysqlConnector` has a constructor but it doesn't works when I do the instance.

I have debugged the code and there is no way to entry in the constructor of `new MysqlConnector();`

```
 <?php
class MysqlConnector 
{
    public $connection;

    function __constuct()
    {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(Config::MYSQL_HOST, Config::MYSQL_DBUSER, Config::MYSQL_DBPASS);
        if(!$this->connection) 
        {
            die("Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db(Config::MYSQL_DBNAME);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    }

    public function __destruct() 
    {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the class where I want to create the `MysqlConnector` object:

```
 <?php
class Config 
{
    const DEBUG_MODE = true;

    const WEB_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
    const WEB_PATH = "c:/Apache2.2/htdocs/";

    const MYSQL_HOST = "localhost";
    const MYSQL_DBNAME = "xxx";
    const MYSQL_DBUSER = "xxx";
    const MYSQL_DBPASS = "xxx";

    public function __construct() 
    {
        if(self::DEBUG_MODE)
        {
            error_reporting(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(0);
        }

        $this->autoLoad();
        new MysqlConnector();
    }

    private function autoLoad()
    {
        require_once self::WEB_PATH . "db/MysqlConnector.php";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Since you are already started with OOP, I suggest that you drop `mysql_*` functions and start learning about PDO (or at least mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

As you have it written now the destructor of MySqlConnector() will run on once __construct() of Config.

You likely want something like `$this->db = new MySqlConnector()`

Also the typo in function name `__construct`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your `class MysqlConnector`

It should be

```
function __construct()
```

Instead of

```
function __constuct()  //<--- You are missing a `r`
```

Comment: like it should be "constructor doesn't work" instead of "constructor doesn't works". I see a pattern ;-)

Comment: Oh my God! Thank you so much and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: :D
I am a big *misspeller* myself